# How to search within the QGIS python console?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-python-console

In the QGIS 3 Python console, there are often lots and lots of messages printed out as various QGIS/PyQGIS functions run.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to search for a specific word or phrase in this message window?

I tried `Ctrl+F` and a few other common shortcut keys, to no avail. I couldn't find it either in the context menu, or the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html) (which only mentions a search bar for the code editor).

(This is with QGIS 3.22, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Comment: When I need to do something like this, I copy and paste all output into VSCode. It has nice highlight and search capabilities.

Comment: No I don't think that option exists in the console. I do the same thing as @KadirŞahbaz - copy and paste the text into an IDE (VScode / PyCharm / Notepad++ / Atom etc)